# Delete objects that does not belong from list - Realm

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

I have a new list of objects to be saved/updated in realm. I want first to delete all objects stored in realm that is not included in my new list before saving/updating the new ones. Any idea on how to do this? (I don't want to delete all my table rows first then save the new ones)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. When you ask a question, try to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way people can understand your problem better and will be able to help u faster. You can also take a look here to start :https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See the first EDIT on the accepted answer on the related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all welcome to StackOverflow & please follow what @teun-van-der-wijst has mentioned in the comments.

Coming to your question,

In realm there is no specific function to `UPDATE` an object. There are 2 ways you can perform an update.

- Delete all the rows of the object and add the new ones. (But since you have mentioned that you do not wish to do this try option 2)
- Use the `WRITE` method to assign a new value to a existing property by using a filter or predicate.

You can follow this link for the documentation: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#updating-objects

This is just a generic example of how to update using `WRITE`

```
let fruits = realm.objects(Fruits.self).filter("date = %@", removeTodaysItem)

let realm = try! Realm()
if let fruit = fruits.first {
    try! realm.write {
        fruit.date = "today's date"
    }
}
```